# Convert SELECT to an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT t1.status, t3.guid, t3.objectID
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID
   AND t1.ID = t2.ID
   AND t3.Guid IN ('', '', '')
```

How can I convert this to an update statement where I set the `t1.status = 1`?

Answer (score 11):

I would start by converting it to using joins instead of "classical joining":

```
select t1.status, t3.guid, t3.objectID
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
inner join Table3 t3 on t3.ID = t2.ID
where t3.Guid in ('', '', '')
```

Then you can just rip of the select statement and slap an update and set statement on it:

```
update t1
set status = 1
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
inner join Table3 t3 on t3.ID = t2.ID
where t3.Guid in ('', '', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
update Table1
set status = 1
from Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
    inner join Table3 t3 on t2.ID = t3.ID
where t3.Guid IN ('', '', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET status = 1
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID
   AND t1.ID = t2.ID
   AND t3.Guid IN ('', '', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table1
set status = 1
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID
   AND t1.ID = t2.ID
   AND t3.Guid IN ('', '', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1 set status = 1 
from table2 t2, table 3 t3 
where t2.ID = t3.ID 
and Table1.ID = t2.ID 
and t3.GUID in ('','','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in MS SQL Server (but not Oracle), you can write:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
set t1.status = 1
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID
   AND t1.ID = t2.ID
   AND t3.Guid IN ('', '', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE
INTO Table1 t1
USING
  (
  SELECT t2.id
  FROM Table2 t2, Table3 t3
  WHERE 
    t3.ID = t2.id
    AND t3.GUID IN ('', '', '')
 ) to
ON t1.id = to.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET t1.status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 set t1.status=(select 1 from Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3 WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID   AND t1.ID = t2.ID  AND t3.Guid IN ('', '', ''))
```